# Could not delete content type from server

Tags: deployment, content

I have a project in Visual Studio, I deployed it once, then I thought of changing the `Name` attribute of the content type, after that when I tried to deploy again, I got this error:

```
Could not delete content type '0x0100B8E5627498B4483C81EA59C41943E122' from server.
```

Knowing that I haven't created any items of this content type, it's just added to a list and that's it, now when I am retracting the solution, the columns inside the content type are deleted, but the content type is not and I have this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to change the names of already deployed content types or fields (internal names)...Always change the GUID otherwise you can get in this trouble...

Rename the CT back, redeploy, retract (and be sure the CT is removed).
Then rename the CT, change the GUID! and deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

First, Remove from

**Site Settings > List templates (Web Designer Galleries)**

and then try to remove from Site content types.